# Bounded Treelist takes time when its source is cleared

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtratreelist

With Dev Express I have a treelist whose datasource is a bindinglist

at some point during an update of the underlying data we manually call:

```
 treeList.LockReloadNodes();
    list.Clear(); // binding list that is bound to the treelist
treeList.UnlockReloadNodes();
```

The problem is that calling clear is extremely slow, since a "element deleted" event is sent to the treelist for *each* of the elements in the list,  so the treelist has to recompute its state as many times as there are elements in the binding list

Do you know if this is the correct way to do this? This obviously gets very slow when I have lots of nodes

Answer (score 0):

I guess you dont't use the [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel), otherwise you can bind to a List with your Models and than just Control your PropertyChanged Events.